# ElasticSearch NEST Search Multiple Types & All Fields

Tags: c#, search, elasticsearch, nest

Using ElasticSearch NEST, I am having trouble getting expected results back from my queries.  My index/type layout is as follows:

- theatres (index)

  - event (types)
  - theatre
  - promotion
  - generic content

Each of those types have their own fields, and I am using NEST's Index() method to index the data.  I can verify that it's being indexed properly by:

- Looking at `http://localhost:9200/theatres/_mapping`
- Using the [Head](http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/) plugin to view data

For reference, here is my client configuration:

```
// TODO: Put settings in config
var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
var connSettings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
connSettings.SetDefaultIndex("theatres");
connSettings.ThrowOnElasticsearchServerExceptions();

var client = new ElasticClient(connSettings);
```

**The Query**

Now, for the query, I want to search *all* types and *all* fields within the index.  Using the Head plugin, I am able to generate the query and get the expected results: [image]

Using that query that it generated, I tried the following NEST query:

```
var query = "waukesha"; // This would be passed in

var resp = client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
   .From(0)
   .Take(10)
   .Query(qry => qry
       .Bool(b => b
       .Must(m => m
           .QueryString(qs => qs
               .DefaultField("_all")
               .Query(query))))));
```

However, this gives me a different result.  Is NEST doing something behind the scenes that I'm not aware of? Or is this not supported?

Comment: I would suggest .Size(10) instead of .Take(20) just to remove that as a variable for error, although the functionality should be the same. Also I believe you can remove .DefaultField and all fields will be searched.  Could you try that? I'm curious about this

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling i updated this and still get 0 results, when I should get 1.

Comment: So weird! Could you add back DefaultField("_all") and also add .AllTypes()? Manually forcing NEST to create a query with all types might give us more info

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling that worked!  After testing that, I changed it to `.AllTypes()` and that also works.  Now I wonder if I can simplify this query?

Comment: Great! Do you mind if I post that as an answer for future people reading this thread? I believe that if you use a simple query or term query it should also function but be slightly more elegant.

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling absolutely! thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your query is missing `.AllTypes()`

You can also specify multiple types using `.Types("type1", "type1")`

So:

```
var query = "waukesha"; // This would be passed in

var resp = client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
   .AllTypes()
   .From(0)
   .Take(10)
   .Query(qry => qry
       .Bool(b => b
       .Must(m => m
           .QueryString(qs => qs
               .DefaultField("_all")
               .Query(query))))));
```

Comment: Can we use type based Term filter here.
Example: Two types: "type1", "type2"
type1 having: name, locationid,
type2 having: countryid and stateid
using this how can we achive type based term filter here?

Comment: @MohanGopi -- Yes: `.Type<Type1>().Type<Type2>()`